# Porque se me duplican los elementos dentro de un RecycleView?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Me gustaria saber porque se me duplican los elementos del Recycle view, cuando en la consola log se ve que la lista de elementos es unicamente 1.

```
var Lista = mutableListOf<Documento>()

       //inicializo la base de datos

       val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

       //--------------------------inicializamos el recycle--------------------------------------------------------------

       val recycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.Recycle)//cogemos el recycle para tenerlo trackeado

       val adapter = CustomAdapter(Lista, object : DocumentoListaListener{
           override fun onDocumentoClickListener(url: String, titulo: String) {
               var url_uri = Uri.parse(url)//obtenemos la url del tipo uri
               var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url_uri)//para ir a una web donde descargar el pdf

               //var intent = Intent(this@MostrarDocumento, WebViewer::class.java)
               //intent.putExtra("url", url)
               //intent.putExtra("titulo", titulo)

               startActivity(intent)//mandamos el intent para migrar a la web
           }
       })

       //inicializamos el adaptador con una lista vacia y llamamos al recycleview
       recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)//pasamos el contexto al recycle
       recycler.adapter = adapter

       //---------------------GlobalScope para ver que se esperan los tiempos de la bd-------------------------------
       GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

           when(Tipo)
           {
               "Horarios" -> {
                   db.collection("Documentos")
                       .whereEqualTo("grado", Grado)
                       .get()
                       .addOnSuccessListener {
                               fbdocuments -> for(docu in fbdocuments)
                       {
                           val docu_lista = docu.toObject(Documento::class.java)
                           Lista.add(docu_lista)

                       }
                           Log.d("Lista de documentos: ", "${Lista}")
                       }
                       .await()
               }

               "Exámenes" -> {
                   db.collection("Examenes")
                       .whereEqualTo("grado", Grado)
                       .get()
                       .addOnSuccessListener {
                               fbdocuments -> for(docu in fbdocuments)
                       {
                           val docu_lista = docu.toObject(Documento::class.java)
                           Lista.add(docu_lista)

                       }
                           Log.d("Lista de documentos: ", "${Lista}")
                       }
                       .await()
               }
           }


           runOnUiThread{
               adapter.setLista(Lista)
           }

       }
       Log.e("Lista documentos: ", "${Lista}")
   }
```

A la hora de hacer el recycleview me imprime el mismo elemento dos veces aunque en el log aparezca solo uno. Y por mas que lo miro no encuentro el porque sucede eso, siendo que como he dicho, en el log veo que la lista tiene un solo documento y al hacer el recycleview se me dibuja dos veces el mismo.

Comment: Debes agregar que tiene setLista()

Comment: Esta incluido como método dentro de la clase de customadapter. 

fun setLista(Lista: MutableList<Documento>)
    {
        this.Documentos.addAll(Lista)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

Answer (score 2):

Antes de agregar elementos a tu Lista mutable `Lista`, te sugiero eliminarlos usando `Lista.clear()`, para evitar se duplique la información.

```
  Lista.clear()  //*Vacía lista, para asegurar no se duplique la información.
  Lista.add(docu_lista) //*Agrega la información.
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! no conocía ese método de la clase lista.